# R-check if a string contains only allowed characters

Tags: r, string

I have a list of allowed characters:

alphanumerics and certain symbols: `+ - $`

How can I check if my string contains only these?

For example, `Avb@` should returm false, but `dn$` should be TRUE.

Preferably, I would like to use base R only.

I have found posts on the same question for other languages, but not in R.

Thank you!

Comment: You're looking for the so called regular expression:
https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/stringr/vignettes/regular-expressions.html

Comment: Closing this as a dupe; the linked post is an example demonstrating the use of regexp in R; you can find many more posts on the use of regexp's through the search.

Comment: I am not familiar with regexp. Is this the only way to go?

Comment: Based on the description of your problem, I'd say the answer is "yes". For example, `grepl` returns `TRUE`/`FALSE` for each matched element.